# Check if file exists in user-defined "Install Location" in C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, wix, wix3.8

I have a project built with WIX Toolkit that deploys a few components as part of a simple installer package (MSI):

- A library, `libtest.dll`
- A header file for the library, `libtest.h`
- A simple application to exercise the library, `libtest_example.exe`

I have a feature in `libtest.dll` which isn't exposed directly to the user, where it checks the `PWD` (present working directory) for a file named `override.raw`. If this file exists, the normal initialization code in `libtest.dll` used by `libtest_example.exe` will behave differently (ie: enable debug logging to console if the application is launched from a console).

I want to integrate a feature into `libtest.dll` so that if it can't find `override.raw` in the `PWD`, it checks where the MSI package was installed to. This is a package I compile for x86 and x64, so the default locations are:

- 32-bit version

  - x86

    - C:\Program Files\42Chickens\libtest
  - x64

    - C:\Program Files (x86)\42Chickens\libtest
- 64-bit version

  - x86

    - WON'T INSTALL
  - x64

    - C:\Program Files\42Chickens\libtest

Of course, the user can change the default install location.

So, what I'm trying to do is determine, within my C++ library, `libtest.dll`, where my software was installed to, and check that location for `override.raw` if it doesn't exist in the PWD.

Is there a trivial way to do this? Even better, is there a way to include some file from my WIX project directly into my C++ source so I only have to change the value in one location? My best guess is I'm querying some sort of GUID/UUID value from the WIX project, and using a Windows system call or Windows SDK command to query a registry entry based off of the key, but that's as far as I've gotten.

I've also written a messy example where WIX adds extra registry keys, but they don't seem to be identical from system-to-system, so I'm seeking help with a portable solution that works in Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8.x, and 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MsiGetComponentPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSI API function to get the key path to a component (usually a file). You could also just write the user's chosen installation directory to the registry and query that from your initialization code. That's probably easier and doesn't require coordinating the product code and component GUIDs.